# Socket.io how create file run time on local server

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have written down this code in NPM module with the help of socket.io,

Index.html

```
<html> <head> <title>WebRTC client</title> </head> <body> 
<script src='socket.io/socket.io.js'></script> </body> </html>
```

In server.js file

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8181);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    console.log('io.sockets.on');        
});
```

Root folder has index.html, server.js, and **socket.io** folder contains no file

Hit localhost:8181 in a browser, index.html will run and socket.io/socket.io.js file automatically created

> http://localhost:8181/socket.io/socket.io.js

and I checked my socket.io folder there is no file? How socket.io.js created? and what is the main purpose of a socket.io/socket.io.js file?

Comment: What are you even trying to do?

Comment: I have created a chat application with socket  and it is working fine but my question is socket.io.js file created run time in socket.io folder  how and what it's do?

Comment: So, you're wondering why a `socket.io.js` file is created when you run your application?

Comment: yes i m want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You might be wondering where the /socket.io/socket.io.js file comes from, since we neither add it and nor does it exist on the filesystem. This is part of the magic done by io.listen on the server. It creates a handler on the server to serve the socket.io.js script file."

from the book Socket.IO Real-time Web Application Development, page 56

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer when it doesn't answer OP's question: `"and what is the main purpose of a socket.io/socket.io.js file?"` ?